# Xml deserializer error only on Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: xml, c#-4.0, xml-deserialization

I am getting an error message "There is an error in XML document (81,6). The error line and column is where the Label tag starts in the example below. I am having this problem on multiple computers, however, all the computers that are having this problem are running Windows Server 2008 R2. The program runs fine on Windows Server 2003 and Windows 7. This problem is also affecting an older version of our software which leads me to believe that it is an environmental issue. Do you have any idea where I should start looking for causes of the problem?

```
<InstallPackage Configuration="Server" Platform="All">
<Path>[RootPath]\Redistributables\SQL Server\MS_SQL_2008_R2_ENT_EDITION\setup.exe</Path>
<Arguments>/SAPWD="[Decrypt:1呫翆夳ᠩ薳⚳鍏꩒髡㩂ꀘ罸๜圓禍᡻뿚荗ந䒩ᨔ]" /ConfigurationFile="[RootPath]\Redistributables\SQL Server\MS_SQL_2008_R2_ENT_EDITION\server.ini"</Arguments>
<Label>Installing Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 Enterprise...</Label>
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem ended up being FIPS being enabled on Windows Server 2008 R2.